# Apple's TestFlight provides old builds

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

My team uses TestFlight to deploy beta builds within the company. Frequently, the TestFlight App does not want to install the latest version.

For example, we will get a TestFlight email informing us about an App update for **build #91**. The email includes a link ""Open in TestFlight". When you tap the link, TestFlight opens, but offers to install **build #90** *(an older build)*, instead of **build #91** *(the latest)*.

- Is this a known problem?
- Are there work arounds to improve the situation?

Comment: File a bug report at Apple, I don't think there is much more you can do.

Comment: Which version of testflight are you using? Are you using the one at http://testflightapp.com or the one through itunesconnect? If it is at http://testflightapp.com they may just ignore the bug that you report as they will be phasing this out.

Comment: @popeye I'm using the version from the App store.

Comment: Wow – this still happens – quality. It's handy that there's an answer for it when I web search!

Comment: Even i got similar issue,If you don't want that build #90, you can expire the build and try to send the invite again. You will get the latest build #91 when you click on view in testflight. Hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

In the "Prereleases" list for your App, once your build has finished processing, you'll be able to click the link for that particular test build and go a page with meta data about it. Switch to the "Test Information" tab.

I had filled "TestFlight Beta Information" section, but empty "Beta App Review Information". After filled second one and saved, I received email and notification about new build available.

### Solution:

**Fill whole form** :P

Comment: Ah – I hadn't filled in any of this (no UI suggesting to do it, of course, thanks iTunes connect)! I just filled in "TestFlight Beta Information", which has "What to Test" and "App Description". I hit save, and the emails went though. So, thanks very much!

Comment: This also sovled my problem, it is so strange and so confusing... I thought Apple would be a better company regarding development.

Comment: "why so much pain for developers apple :("
strange, two of my build uploaded successfully with invitation mail without filling anything, but for one of the build i have to fill "What to Test", and mail sent immediately. weired

Comment: This is still a thing now. And the woraround didnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I must emphasize that currently, there are 2 ways to force iTunes Connect to push the update out:

1) Enter meta data and update the build.

2) Disable TestFlight Beta Testing, and re-Enable it.

But these are both workarounds; internal testing is not supposed to work this way.

I have attempted to file a bug report to Apple Support as detailed in another post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27197057/4305185

I suggest you guys try the same; more reports means more chance of them actually seeing one of them.

Comment: Good stuff – more reports are better!

Answer (score 2):

Lots of helpful answers here – thank you everyone.

I just noticed something interesting.

I set up the "What to test" info *before* the new build had finished being in the "Processing" state (the other info is copied over for a new build). When it completed processing, no messages were sent.

I went back to the build info and changed "What to test" enough to enable a Save. On hitting Save, the TestFlight notifications were *immediately* sent to the test devices I have (and I assume to my colleagues' too).

On this build I have the "What to Test", "App Description" and "Feedback Email" fields set, but I have left the other fields blank.

I suspect that **any save operation** in this form **after the build finishes "Processing"** is enough to fire off the update emails. If you fill in everything, it takes you longer, and you are more likely to press `Save` once "Processing" has finished :-)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same problem but was able to fix it. I went to the meta data section of new build and added added some text and did a save. And now my build became active and the emails were sent to internal testers.