# Apple TestFlight provide old build

Tags: ios, testflight

When i update/upload the new release at Apple TestFlight my testers, and me, get an old build of my app.

I have removed the old version from TestFlight but still receive that version. The weird thing is that it states that they have installed the current build but it is the old they get.

There is a lot posts about this problem but it seems that TestFlight have changed so I am not able to get it to work and it may looks different.

Tried this, and others: [Apple's TestFlight provides old builds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27122771/apples-testflight-provides-old-builds)

...with no success.

Anyone that can provide some help on this?

Comment: I've run into the same issue and only just saw your post now. I've found that restarting the device will let you run the new build, but haven't found any way of avoiding that yet. My question is linked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50497051/testflight-app-runs-old-code-after-updating-to-new-build

Comment: Restarting doesnt work for me. what other work around is available

Comment: I think I know. why this is happen. Unless the tester(s) is registered developers the build must be approved by Apple before the build is available for test with these people.